# HttpContext is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm doing a Blazor server-side project and I need the `HttpContext` into my `SignInService` so the `SignInManager` service can sign in an user. I updated the `Startup.cs` file as such :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<LogInService>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); //Line added
    }
```

However, the `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is always null, either on client or server side.

Why so ? Did I missed something into the startup ? I should normally have the context through dependency injection `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` yet it doesn't occur.

**Edit :** This is the `SignInService` that need to use `HttpContext` :

```
 public class SignInService
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public SignInService(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager) 
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task<SignInResult> TrySignIn(LogInForm logInForm)
        {
            return await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(logInForm.Mail, logInForm.Password, false, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where it's always null ?

Comment: You say you're doing a Blazor server side project...yet you also saying it's always null on the client or server side. How do you know it's null on the client side if you're doing a server side project?

Comment: Use `IHttpContextAccessor` as a dependency and use that instead.

Comment: @aguafrommars everywhere I inject `IHttpContextAccessor`, it's initializing the service but `HttpContext` is always null

Comment: @mason You're right, I don't know about the client because everything is happening on the server. I misunderstood with the pages. But then that means the client isn't sending the  `HttpContext` to the sever.

Comment: Ok, where to you inject `IHttpContextAccessor` ? Can you post a sample ? You can use an `HttpContext` just during a request, so in your constructors it will be null.

Comment: @aguafrommars Specifically, in my `SignInService` as `private readonly` variable, which is initialized through constructor by DI. I edited my main post to add the code of the service.

Comment: Do you use the `SigninService` in controller's web method?

Comment: @aguafrommars What do you mean ? I use the `SignInService` directly into my `SignIn.razor` component, like this : `result = await _SignInService.TrySignIn(logInForm);`

Comment: Clients do not *send* an HttpContext to the server. The server creates an instance, based on the HTTP request that it receives.

Comment: You can't do that, Your Razor component run on the client, so there isn't HttpContext.

Comment: You should steer away from using HttpContext in your Blazor app anyways - that ties your Blazor app to the server side. The ultimate goal is running Blazor on the client side once that's supported, right? So HttpContext won't be available then. Anything that needs to deal with server resources should be talking to a Web API or SignalR.

Comment: @aguafrommars No, it's not running on the client. He's doing [server side Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Comment: Ok, let's say it run on the server. However it is in a `SignalR` context where you don't have an `HttpContext`.

Comment: To me, the question isn't relevant as to whether you will or will not have an HttpContext. You simply shouldn't use HttpContext in a Blazor project. Even if it's running on the server, you should write it *as if it's running on the client*. That means no file system access, no HttpContext, no database access. It all needs to go through the same communication channels back to a seperate server side app, just like if we were doing an Angular/Vue/React/VanillaJS SPA site.

Comment: @mason fully agree

Comment: @mason Ok so I misunderstood how to use Blazor. Sorry, still learning. At first I tried communication with Http Get/Post but it wasn't working and I got misguided in the end to use only services. So I should use SignalR for the client and the server to communicate, if I was doing a SPA site ?

Comment: SignalR is one way of doing things, though I tend to reserve that when I need to push data from the server to the client (although it's capable of client to server calls too). Another would be Web API (part of ASP.NET Core MVC) running on the server side, then using HttpClient from your Blazor app to communicate to it.

Comment: @mason Ah crap, that was what I using at first but never got the routes to work. Guess I'll have to study harder. Thanks a lot, you're the hero I don't deserve

Comment: Think of Blazor as a replacement for the client side logic of your site....most of the time you'll still need something running on the server side for your app to talk to, and a way for them to communicate. So you'll still need to know some sort of server side framework. Note that it doesn't have to be ASP.NET Core MVC (though that probably makes the most sense if you're familiar with .NET and/or you want to achieve more code reuse). You could use any sort of web framework from Java, Python, PHP etc.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Blazor server-side is only used for client purposes and services are just middlewares. I understand much more now, thanks.