# Using SignInManager in server-side Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to use `SignInManager` without having some `HTTPContext` ? I'm making a Blazor server-side app and I need to make end-users signed in using `PasswordSignInAsync()` method of `SignInManager`.

If there is other ways to do it with cookies or something else, I'll take it too, as long they are "clean" methods.

If I could get also an explanation on how to configure for `Startup.cs` the solution, it will be perfect.

Comment: If you're doing things server-side, then you will have an `HttpContext` so I don't understand what you are asking here?

Comment: @DavidG - no, the server hands over to SgnalR and you __do not have a HttpContext__ in Blazor.

Comment: Specify what you mean by 'clean'. The templates provide you with a well worked out Identity setup. The Razor pages there are required (at last the Login one) precisely to get at the HttpContext and the cookies.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I meant by using the `SignInManager` or something already build-in to take the login in charge. Besides, I took the template with user authentification, but the only reference to a login page is in `Shared.LoginDisplay.razor` where there's a link to some `/Identity/Account/Login` file but it's nowhere to be found. I would have checked it otherwise, to know how it's handled in blazor server side.

Comment: For that you need to look up "Scaffolding Identity". The Blazor version may still need some small fixing afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpContext is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936806/httpcontext-is-always-null)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok I looked at the scaffolded `Login.cshtml` and actually it's done with `PasswordSignInAsync()` in the controller, which I was using but inside a service, which is stupid as to get an `HTTPContext`, you need an actual HTTP request to transmit it. My bad. Thanks for your indications. What are those fixes you were talking ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I'll mark the other as duplicate of this one, as I think this thread answer more both questions.

Answer (score 0):

To use SignInManager in server-side Blazor,

First, add`AddIdentity` service into `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;    
        })
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then, Inject `SignInManager` into your razor page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject NavigationManager navManager;

<!-- Put Login Form Here -->

@code{
 protected async Task Submit()
 {
    var SignInResult= await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("username", "password", true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (SignInResult.Succeeded)
    {
       navManager.NavigateTo("Home", false);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You may encounter the following issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13601

Comment: I don't think this solution will actually work because of the issue you mentioned. I think it's rather a "you will encounter" rather than "you may"?

Comment: SignInManager manager does not work server side.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins: `SignInManager manager does not work server side.` No, why not ? Why shouldn't it work in Blazor Server ? Please, go on learnng Blazor without misleading others. All you've said in this question is base less and wrong.

Comment: @enet - I have tried several ways to get `SignInManager` to work server side. As pointed out by Mustafa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973878/using-signinmanager-in-server-side-blazor/68578622?noredirect=1#comment121205397_68578622 SignInManager attempts to set auth cookie, but since Serverside blazor works over SignalR an error is thrown `System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started`

Comment: To be clear, you can REDIRECT to a non-blazor page to set an auth cookie and then redirect back to your blazor application but that is not the same thing as working inside of blazor.

Comment: `"SignInManager<TUser> and UserManager<TUser> aren't supported in Razor components. "` Emphsize is on 'Razor components,'  But alas, I can inject the SignInManager into a service class and use it, as if I redirect to a Web Api end point or to a Razor Page.  Thus, saying: `SignInManager manager does not work server side.` is misleading and providing no usefull value

Answer (score 0):

There's another way that nobody has mentioned, so thought I might as well: you could use middleware to login, since middleware carries the full html request and can modify it (for example, by logging in), before it follows the pipeline to Blazor rendering.  I use this method for creating temporary guest users for my gaming pages-- which works because the guest doesn't need to type in and submit their own password
as plaintext.

The logistics of making the login secure would probably not be easier than following @enet's advice of using the built-in scaffolded Authentication system, or of logging in using UserManager and re-navigating to your page.  You could, however, use a modal box to sign in, rather than having to navigate to the MVC-style login page.

Answer (score -1):

I'd strongly suggest that you use the Identity authentication system in your app.
You should not try to create any authentication system instead. This is something free, and is set up within a couple of minutes. Don't waste your time to do something so complicated. Instead learn what are the Blazor Authorization components and how to use them in your application. They are great.

Note: The communication between Blazor Server and its client-side is done through SignaleR. HttpContext is not available most of the time. Do not try to use the HttpContext. Actually, you can't because whenever you try to access it, it is null.

The following describe how you can create a Blazor Server App with the Identity UI:

- Start creating a Blazor App
- In the window titled Create a new Blazor app do this:

  1. Select Blazor Server App
  2. On the right side of the window is a link with the text Change, under the Authentication title. Tap the link and select Individual User Account. Press OK...
  3. Click the "Create" button

Visual Studio has created for you a Blazor Server App with Identity UI to authenticate your users. Note that the Identity UI is actually the Razor Pages Identity UI used with Razor Pages and MVC. You may scaffold one or more items from this system if you need to make some changes. Go to solution explorer and verify that Visual Studio has added two folders named Areas and Data. She also has configured your Startup class with the necessary services to mange the Identity UI. What you want now is to create the database where user names, roles, claims, etc. are stored. To create the database you should use *migrations*. [Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/index?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) telling you how to run the commands that do the job for you. Now you can run your app, register to the web site, login, logout, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I searched a bit, and I found ways to do it myself. But in the end, you must use a .cshtml page to do the login, it can't go through a .razor componenet or page. There is a workaround to this which is to put the username and password in an URL and send it from the razor component to the Login controller through a GET request, but everyone would scream that this is an atrocity and I won't risk myself in this terrain even with HTTPS. Thanks, I was stuck on this question for a few days.

Comment: @PepperTiger, understand this: The Login page displayed for the user is a .cshtml file (Razor Pages). This is only to collect data from the user and authenticate it. But there are Blazor components that are used to authorize the user, send him back to reconnect, etc. They are all Blazor components, and they are superb, and work in association with the Identity UI( Razor Pages). If you have followed the instruction in my answer, then you can view those components, added and used in the app you might have created. Go find them and learn how to use them. Look for AuthorizeView and learn what it

Comment: does. Don't look for workaround. Actually what do you mean by workaround. There is no need for such thing. Everything has already been created for you...

Comment: I was more into the "do your own thing" vision as I wanted to learn one thing or two about how a web app should manage authentication, authorization and security of users information. Guess then I don't have to do this the hard way, just have to read some docs. But I mostly got the other basics of a Blazor app, thanks for you concern though.

Comment: I don't like this answer as there are more than 3 tutorials around with the same example, and I don't have visual Studio as I'm a Linux user. Another huge argument against is that I've already have a Database with Users, I don't want the default Microsoft solution for it.

Comment: @enet My blazor server app is packaged as an electron desktop app & cant have identity built in, it only has access to an external cloud Jwt server, how can the blazor app sign in using only a jwt?

Comment: This is not an answer. It requires rolling out your own scaffolded identity solution and does NOT use blazor. It instead requires using scaffolding csthml razor pages which requires an entirely separate website template/pipeline and redirect.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins, So why don't you provide an answer of your own ? `It requires rolling out your own scaffolded identity solution.` That's true... So ?  ` and does NOT use blazor.` True. It does not use Blazor. Can you roll out your own identity system that uses Blazor ? Please do it as an answer. Take your time. I'M WAITING FOR YOUR ANSWER !