# Accessing Http.Context in AuthenticationStateProvider on Blazor Server app

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

When authenticating the application, I want to check for existence of some headers and their values in the current request. There is an authentication gateway that will be on the IIS server and will be handling authentication of users. Then they will be passing me values in the header, one of which being a username. Would I be able to just use the JwtBearer options for authenticating in my application or would I need to override the AuthenticationStateProvider to manually pull the values and retrieve user data stored in my application database?

Comment: What type of Blazor do you want to use with JwtBearer , client-side or server-side ?

Comment: Server side Blazor is what the plan is, as of today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `HttpContext` in a Blazor component.

Read comment on this question:
[Using SignInManager in server-side Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973878/using-signinmanager-in-server-side-blazor)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and inject

```
IHttpContextAccessor
```